# Recovery failed: File too large- MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

2021-12-29T20:31:45.299+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=27670M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2021-12-29T20:32:36.053+0530 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (27) [1640790156:53082][2504:0x7f648fab1e40], file:collection-295-7483509143911416327.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: /var/lib/mongo/collection-295-7483509143911416327.wt: handle-write: pwrite: failed to write **77824 bytes at offset 17592186040320: File too large**
2021-12-29T20:32:36.056+0530 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (27) [1640790156:56009][2504:0x7f648fab1e40], file:collection-2-4265086470975275238.wt, txn-recover: Recovery failed: File too large
2021-12-29T20:32:36.059+0530 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (22) [1640790156:59702][2504:0x7f648fab1e40], file:index-4006--6574301648255084090.wt, connection: index-4006--6574301648255084090.wt: unexpected checkpoint ordering: Invalid argument
2021-12-29T20:32:36.059+0530 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (-31804) [1640790156:59759][2504:0x7f648fab1e40], file:index-4006--6574301648255084090.wt, connection: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2021-12-29T20:32:36.059+0530 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28558 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_util.cpp 361
2021-12-29T20:32:36.059+0530 I -        [initandlisten]

***aborting after fassert() failure

2021-12-29T20:32:36.077+0530 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

Could you pleas help me here.

Comment: How did you create the backup and how do you try to restore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using EXT3, the maximum file size for EXT3 is 2TB so the "File too large" error is expected for a 2 TB data

You must upgrade your filesystem to XFS and EXT4.

Check out this link about file system from MongoDB:

[kernel-and-file-systems](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#kernel-and-file-systems)

and this to check the ulimit setting:
[ulimits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/)

Comment: We are using EXT4

Comment: Do you check the ulimit settings?

Comment: EXT4 has a file size limit of 16 TiB.  The offset mentioned in the error message (17592186040320) is 15.99 TiB.  It is 4096 bytes less than 16TiB, so writing 77824 bytes at that point will definitely push it over the limit.